# How to programmatically get the list of directories that brew installs to?

Tags: macos, bash, zsh, homebrew

I am writing a script that automates setting up my mac dev environment. I want to place the directories that brew installs first on my path, so that the default system commands are overridden by brew installs. I know brew installs to /usr/local/Cellar, /usr/local/Caskroom and places symlinks in /usr/local/opt/ but I want to get this information programmatically in case the default directories that brew installs to change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`Cellar` is the default directory used by `brew` for quite a while now, and the same with `Caskroom` for `brew cask`. These are ***very*** unlikely to change as it would result in a significant amount of migration work for both the developers and the users, for very little benefit.

More interesting is the installation prefix - namely where those two folders are located. Those could very well change if Apple decides to play around with `/usr/local/` in the future.

If you want to get the current prefix, run `brew config | grep HOMEBREW_PREFIX`.

As to the actual symlinks that point to the install apps, these are placed into `/usr/local/bin` (again, respecting `HOMEBREW_PREFIX`, with `/usr/local/bin` being placed into your path).

If Apple somehow restricts the use of `/usr/local`, everything could be repointed by modifying `HOMEBREW_PREFIX` to a different directory, with the `bin` winding up in your path, and Homebrew using the `Cellar` and `Caskroom` directories under the new prefix.